# Are there any adverse impacts if I keep WiFi router on all time?

Tags: environmental-impact, computing

I searched [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=can%20i%20keep%20my%20router%20on%20all%20the%20time&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIN867IN867&oq=can%20i%20keep%20router%20on&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5055j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) only to come up with various results with different views. Is there any official or reliable source that states the impacts of keeping the WiFi router on regarding environmental impact, carbon footprint and personal health impacts?

Comment: Well, I guess somewhere on your router there's info on how much Watt it "has". Aiming for the worst case: Multiply this number by 24, then by 365 - voila, you know, how many Wh your router guzzles up if it runs 24/7 at full power. The carbon footprint depends on your energy mix. Ask your energy provider, how much CO2 is in a Wh, multiply it with your consumption and there you are. As to personal health... unless you sleep directly on top of the router and/or amplify the signal significantly, there's no harm.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this link](http://energyusecalculator.com/electricity_wifirouter.htm), an average router will use 6w. Leaving it on all the time will therefore use approximately 0.14kWh per day - about the same as using a 60W laptop for 2.4 hours, or boiling a kettle once.

While it will make a tiny difference if you turn it off, there are many other things you can do that will save a lot more energy.

Comment: Indeed. The most energy-intensive things in our daily lives include home heating, home cooling, and transportation (gasoline for cars).

Comment: I've reduced my consumption by a good few tens of watts by looking at little loads, but the router stays on except when I'm on holiday: If I forget just once to turn it on, my desktop draws more power in the time it takes for the router to boot than I'd save in a month (it's not a powerful desktop, but it is a slow router)

Comment: +1 It might not make much sense when talking individually, but it could be a good candidate for being on a circuit controlled by a timer with other electronics (like TVs/DVD Players/Game Consoles etc that have an 'idle off' state. Especially if you aren't home 8am-6pm - having it switch 'on' at 6pm and off at 12am for example, would save 18 hours of runtime. If everyone did this, that's a lot of idle juice saved!